# Let $A \in \mathbb{Q}^{m \times n}$ with full row rank. Then the matrix $B$ in $A$’s Hermite Normal Form $[B \quad 0]$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, unimodular-matrices, hermite-normal-form

My lecture introduces several new definitions and theorems as below. The part about the matrix $B$ is a passing remark that I’d like to have some more elaboration.

> **Definition 1**. Let $A$ be a $m \times n$ rational matrix. The matrix $A$ is in Hermite Normal Form $(\mathrm{HNF})$ if $A=[B \quad 0]$ where $B$ is lower-triangular, has non-negative integers, with the diagonal entry being the unique maximum entry in each row.

> **Theorem 1**. Any rational matrix $M$ of full row rank can be converted to $\mathrm{HNF}$ by a sequence of elementary column operations which involve:
> (i) exchanging columns,
> (ii) multiplying a column by $-1,$ and
> (iii) adding an integral multiple of one column to another.

By this theorem, HNF $(M)=M C$ for some non-negative integral matrix $C .$ Hence, the HNF of an integral matrix will always be integral.

> **Corollary 1**. If $M$ is integral, then $\mathrm{HNF}(\mathrm{M})$ is also integral.

Moreover, if $A$ has full row-rank, then we can assume $C$ to be a unimodular matrix.

> **Definition 2**. A matrix $U$ is unimodular if it is integral and $\operatorname{det}(U) \in\{\pm 1\}$.

Note: $U$ is unimodular iff $U^{-1}$ is unimodular.

> **Theorem 2**. If $M$ has full row rank, then:
> (i) $\operatorname{HNF}(M)$ is unique and
> (ii) there exists a unimodular matrix $U$ such that $H N F(M)=M U$

By theorem 1, $\mathrm{HNF}(A) = AU$ for some unimodular matrix $U$. The note goes on to say that $AU = [B \quad 0]$ where $B$ is invertible. Why is it so?

Comment: Something is bizarre about your lecture notes. It makes sense that an **integer** matrix can be converted to Hermite normal form, but the steps that are described are not enough to begin with a rational matrix and end with an integer matrix. If your notes allow an HNF matrix to have non-integer entries, then your notes use a non-standard definition.

Comment: I’ve noticed that in this class the distinction between rational entries and integer ones is not always made clear. I just assume the lecturer just left out the scaling procedure.

Comment: From the above definition of the HNF form, I assume we must have $m \leq n$? Otherwise, we should have $A = \begin{bmatrix} B \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$?